# How to display circle avatar on AppBar?

Tags: flutter, dart

I am trying to display Circle Avatar on AppBar.

Here is my code

```
AppBar(
    ...
    actions: <Widget>[
        CircleAvatar(
            radius: 14,
            backgroundImage: userProfilePictureValue != null
                ? NetworkImage(
                    userProfilePictureValue,
                )
                : Icon(Icons.add), 
        )
)
```

Here is the second way which I tried

```
AppBar(
    ...
    actions: <Widget>[
        Container(
            width: 20,
            height: 20,
            decoration: BoxDecoration(
                borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10),
                color:Colors.blueGrey
            ),
            child: StreamBuilder<String>(
                stream: userProfilePicture,
                builder: (context, snapshot) {
                    return ClipOval(
                        child: userProfilePictureValue != null
                            ? CachedNetworkImage(
                                imageUrl:
                                    "${userProfilePictureValue}",
                                fit: BoxFit.fill,
                             )
                            : Icon(
                                Icons.person,
                                size: 40,
                                color: Colors.white,
                            ),
                    );
            }),
    )]
)
```

In first case the image is not displayed as circular and in second case it is displayed as egg shaped instead of circular.

Comment: I tried to run your first code and it gives an error.Try to change `backgroundimage` to `child`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can wrap it in a FlatButton like

```dart
FlatButton(
  child: CircleAvatar(
    backgroundImage: AssetImage("your_image"),
  ),
)
```

Answer (score 0):

Your first option is the correct approach. The reason its not appearing circular is because of the radius you defined and image size you are using.  Here is a [live](https://dartpad.dev/8bab0c04115d8778692439c6c0206021) example of the same with correct radius according to image.

Your options are

1. define correct radius according to the image size you are using.
2. Re-scale the image if required.
3. When your network image is null dont pass an icon to `backgroundImage` since it expects and `ImageProvider` and not Icon. So it will fail in this case.